# F# Charting No Automatic Axis Range Setting?

Tags: f#, fsharpchart

It's not really an issue, more of a question. I am using FSharp.Charting to graph a few quick things. One thing I noticed is that the chart doesn't automatically set the axis limits for you. Say I have a list of numbers that has values between 100,000 and 200,000. The y-axis will still be based at 0. It doesn't scale to give you a good view of the data. You have to do this yourself. Or maybe there is a way, and I just haven't figured it out yet. Has anyone else ran into this issue? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched the [FSharp charting code](https://github.com/fslaborg/FSharp.Charting/blob/master/src/FSharp.Charting.fs) on GitHub and found nothing built in that can do automatic alignment of any axis. The best one can do is do it manually or write a function to look at all the values and then set them based on that.

Since you did not show in your question how to set it manually I will state it here for those that don't know how it is done.

To manually set the Y axis use `WithYAxis`

```
let xs1 = [ for x in (double)(-100.0) .. 1.0 .. 100.0 do yield x]
let ys1 = xs1 |> List.map (fun x -> x**4.00)
let values1 = List.zip xs1 ys1
Chart.Line(values1)
    .WithXAxis(Min=(-30.0), Max=(30.0), MajorTickMark = ChartTypes.TickMark(Interval=10.0, IntervalOffset = 5.0, LineWidth = 2))
    .WithYAxis(Min=(100000.0), Max=(200000.0), MajorTickMark = ChartTypes.TickMark(Interval=20000.0, IntervalOffset = 10000.0, LineWidth = 2))
```

[image]